# How to display value from a specific field in the db?

Tags: database, tags

I want to display the com_tags tag title in a module while on the "Tagged Items" menu item page.

My goal is for this code to display the title for the current tag.  For example,  when on this page: /index.php?option=com_tags&view=tag&id=20, the tag title for id=20 should be displayed.

I found this code but I don't understand the WHERE code.

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
    ->select('title')  
    ->from($db->quoteName('lfco8__tags'))
    ->where($db->qn('id') . " = " . $_GET['id'])
    ;
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadResult();
print_r($result);
```

Please reply with different code if there is something better like some json code or other.

Comment: The WHERE code is a filter saying only return records that match the `id` of the tag you want to retrieve, in this case `$item->id`. If the tag you want to retrieve is called `Fred` and has an `id` of `505` then the WHERE clause would look like `WHERE \`id\` = '505'` or `WHERE \`id\` = $item->id`, where `$item->id` equals `505`. The `$db->qn()` & `$db->q()` are Joomla functions that make sure the values each side of the operator are correctly wrapped in quotes. They are not required, but good practice to include them. Without a WHERE clause you would get all records returned in the result.

Comment: My goal is for this code to display the title for the current tag.  For example,  when on this page: `/index.php?option=com_tags&view=tag&id=20`, the tag title for `id=20` should be displayed.

Comment: Where is this code placed exactly?

Comment: I see a typo in `->>where` <-- too many `>`'s.

Comment: @Sharky The code is in a custom_html module using Regular Labs Sourcerer.

Comment: @mickmackusa I fixed the typo but the issue is still the $this is not current to get the current id that matches the one in the url.

Comment: You need to get the ID from input https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput

Comment: ok, still learning. So I can get the id in the url with $_GET['id'] . What is the exact syntax to insert that into the where?

Comment: THIS ISN'T RIGHT:          ->where($db->qn('id') . " = " . $_GET['id'])

Comment: @mickmackusa Can you please help me write this WHERE line with $_GET['id'] ?

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you tried after reading the link that Sharky provided. @modern

Comment: Ok, I edited my question to contain the $_GET['id']

Comment: Please re-read the link that Sharky provided.